# Refused to execute script from 'URL' because its MIME type ('application/json') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cors, mime-types

I know this question has been asked many times, but in my condition. Firefox is working but chrome is giving me this error:

`Refused to execute script from 'http://localhost:3000/get_all_test_centers?callback=undefined&_=1409807050144' because its MIME type ('application/json') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.`

I have a wordpress website from where I am sending a REST call to rails server (jsonp request). I made below changes for CORS in RAILS

**mime_types.rb**

`Mime::Type.register 'application/json', :js`

**application_controller.rb**

```
before_filter :set_access_control_headers
def set_access_control_headers
    headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = Rails.application.secrets.website_url
    headers['Access-Control-Request-Method'] = 'GET, OPTIONS, HEAD'
    headers['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = 'x-requested-with,Content-Type, Authorization'
  end
```

`Rails.application.secrets.website_url` value is `http://localhost/`

Controller output:

```
def get_all_test_centers
test_centers = TestCenter.all
respond_to do |format|
  format.js do
    render :json => test_centers, :callback => 'renderTestCenters'
  end
end
end
```

My wordpress JS:

```
var renderTestCenters = function(data) {
    console.log(data);
};

$.ajax({
    url: "http://localhost:3000/get_all_test_centers",
    crossDomain: true,
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "JSONP",
    jsonpCallback: renderTestCenters
});
```

It works fine in firefox but in chrome it gives me error.

Answer (score 1):

So finally I got the answer.

Change your ajax request call.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://localhost:3000/get_all_test_centers",
    crossDomain: true,
    xhrFields: {
        withCredentials: true
    },
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

Application_controller.rb

```
before_filter :cor
def cor
if request.headers["HTTP_ORIGIN"]
  headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = Rails.application.secrets.website_url
  headers['Access-Control-Expose-Headers'] = 'ETag'
  headers['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = 'GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS, HEAD'
  headers['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = '*,x-requested-with,Content-Type,If-Modified-Since,If-None-Match,Auth-User-Token'
  headers['Access-Control-Max-Age'] = '86400'
  headers['Access-Control-Allow-Credentials'] = 'true'
end
end
```

And finally in my controller:

```
def get_all_test_centers
test_centers = TestCenter.all
respond_to do |format|
  format.js do
    render :json => test_centers
  end
end
end
```

Now above changes is working in all browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the result isn’t handled directly by a script, so the :callback option is provided for these cases.

`render json: test_centers, :callback => params[:callback]`

This worked for me.